# Cosmos Array_Contains Behavior in Different Partitions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In a Cosmos db, I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    value app
FROM 
    Appointments app
where 
    app.PartitionKey = 'PartitionKey1'
    and array_contains(app.Document.participant, 
    {
        "type": [
            {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/ParticipationType",
                        "code": "LOC",
                        "display": "Location"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, true)
```

This works properly returning expected results.

However, if I remove the "system" and "display" items under "coding", making it

```
"coding": [
    {
        "code": "LOC"
    }
]
```

the query works for Partition1 but not for Partition2, even though documents are structured the same, similar to:

```
[
    {
        "Document": {
            "participant": [
                {
                    "type": [
                        {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/ParticipationType",
                                    "code": "LOC",
                                    "display": "Location"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "actor": {
                        "reference": "Lo1",
                        "display": "Location1"
                    },
                    "required": "required"
                },
                {
                    "type": [
                        {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/ParticipationType",
                                    "code": "SBJ",
                                    "display": "Patient"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "actor": {
                        "reference": "Pa1",
                        "display": "Patient1"
                    },
                    "required": "required"
                },
                {
                    "type": [
                        {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/ParticipationType",
                                    "code": "PRF",
                                    "display": "Provider"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "actor": {
                        "reference": "Pr1",
                        "display": "Provider1"
                    },
                    "required": "required"
                }
            ]
        },
        "PartitionKey": "Partition1"
    }
]
```

The mysterious part is why this would work with one partition key but not another. It's almost as if one partition respects the `true` parameter of array_contains but the other partition does not.

Is there a setting on a partition, or some other property, that changes the behavior of array_contains?

Comment: Did you change the where clause so that app.PartitionKey = 'PartitionKey2' ?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, a query with all 3 items: system, code, display work for both partitions. But when I remove system and display, the query only returns results in Partition1.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of these documents you're expecting to get back?

Comment: The example is the 3rd block of code above. The documents have identical structure in each partition and the "coding" blocks are the same... it's only the "actor" blocks that change between documents.

Comment: That's your first doc you have above. I'd like to see what the doc that does not come back in your query.

Comment: That's the thing... they're the same docs, just different partition key, say, Partition2